# SQL Time exceeds

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, time

I currently have a system that outputs a waiting time, given their arrival time and current time; (current time - arrival time). How would I programme the code so that;

```
if the waiting_time exceeds 3 hours then alert "patient must be seen next!"
```

Here is the code I have so far to calculate waiting_time.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_time, TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), Arrival_time)),'%H hours') as Waiting_Time FROM Patient";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PatientID</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Illness</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Waiting Time</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){

 echo "<tr>
  <td>" . $row->PatientID . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Forename . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Surname . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Gender . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Illness . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Priority . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Waiting_Time . "</td>
  </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: you cab check how many minutes passed between arrival time and current time and if is > 180 (3 hours * 60 min) then display some sort of alert/ notification. Also you can order by wait time desc SELECT NOW(), TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-03-26 08:24;15', NOW()) AS WaitTime, IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-03-26 08:24;15', NOW()) >= 180, 'alert', 'na');  Hope this helps

Comment: how do i check how many minutes has passed between arrival time and current time?

Comment: check syntax for TIMESTAMPDIFF

Comment: Could you provide an example as an answer please

Comment: SELECT NOW(), TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-03-26 08:24;15', NOW()) AS WaitTime, IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-03-26 08:24;15', NOW()) >= 180, 'alert', 'na');

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c69bd/1

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question with a new SQL statement. If you could modify this with your answer please

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/8jd-zqs is working for FireFox(not IE). I am not a php user but this is just dummy sample and should be enough for you to figure out further.

Comment: @AndaIancu `Patient`, not `Pacient`.

Comment: oh typo and like i mentioned just dummy test

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_time,
          TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), Arrival_time)),'%H hours') as Waiting_Time 
          FROM Patient
          ORDER BY TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), Arrival_time) DESC";
```

Then your results are ordered with the longest wait first.

```
<?php

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()): ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?=$row->PatientID?></td>
    <td><?=$row->Forename?></td>
    <td><?=$row->Surname?></td>
    <td><?=$row->Gender?></td>
    <td><?=$row->Illness?></td>
    <td><?=$row->Priority?></td>
    <td><?=$row->Waiting_Time?>
        <? if ($row->Waiting_Time >= 3): ?>
            <strong>Patient must be seen!</strong>
        <? endif; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>

<? endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: No I have not. I'm not going to create this schema just to test this